# eXist-db getting data from many XMLs of the same collection

Tags: java, groovy, xquery, exist-db, openehr

I'm new to using eXist-db. Using Java/Groovy I am trying (with no luck) to get data from a collection I created: `/db/apps/compositions`.

In `/db/apps/compositions` are a couple of XML documents that look similar to this:

```
<version xmlns="http://schemas.openehr.org/v1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ORIGINAL_VERSION">
  ...
  <data xsi:type="COMPOSITION" archetype_node_id="openEHR-EHR-COMPOSITION.signos.v1">
    <name>
      <value>xxxxx</value>
    </name>
    ...
  </data>
</version>
```

I am using the XQJ API in my client side code. I tried to adapt the example code (from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery_API_for_Java and http://xqj.net/exist/):

```
XQDataSource xqs = new ExistXQDataSource();
xqs.setProperty("serverName", "localhost");
xqs.setProperty("port", "8080");

XQConnection conn = xqs.getConnection("user","pass");

XQExpression expr = conn.createExpression();

XQResultSequence result = expr.executeQuery(
  "for $n in fn:collection('/db/apps/compositions')//data " +
  "return fn:data($n/name/value)"); // execute an XQuery expression

// Process the result sequence iteratively
while (result.next()) {
  // Print the current item in the sequence
  System.out.println("Product name: " + result.getItemAsString(null));
}

// Free all resources created by the connection
conn.close();
```

I expected to get the xxxxx texts from all the XML Document in the `/db/apps/compositions` collection but I get no results and no exceptions are thrown.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot!

BTW: I tried to find other ways of implementing a java client, but couldn't find a clear guideline or tutorial for beginners.

Comment: The `data` element belongs to the default namespace declared on `version`. You can either introduce this namespace in your code or wildcard it by writing `*:data`.

Comment: If you are looking for Java client examples, the eXist book dedicates  the entirety of `Chapter 13 - Integration` to looking at the options and writing clients in Java: http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026525.do

The book should be in print next month. However in the mean time the code examples from the integration chapter (including XQJ) are available here: https://github.com/eXist-book/book-code/tree/master/chapters/integration

Answer (score 4):

The problem you have is all about namespaces; your  element is in default namespace so you need to define that namespace in your query.

```
xquery version "3.0";

declare default element namespace "http://schemas.openehr.org/v1";

for $n in fn:collection('/db/apps/compositions')//data

return fn:data($n/name/value)
```

read more in e.g. the [tech wiki](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XQuery/eXist_Crib_sheet#declare_a_namespace)

In general I'd recommend to test queries in the the excellent [eXide](http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/eXide/docs/doc.html) IDE first before merging them into code. The IDE provides you fast feedback on query results so you can play a bit with your queries.

Note that writing

```
*:data
```

might slowdown queries on large datasets.

Comment: Now the query is is getting results, just have one more issue:

The version/data element also has descendant nodes named "data" and also with a name/value element, and the query is getting the name of all the descendants.

Is there a way of getting just the name/value of the first data element?

BTW, this is my modified code in Groovy: https://github.com/ppazos/clinical-database-tests/blob/master/src/existdb/TestExistDB.groovy

Comment: Please an an explicit XML example, I don't understand what you write, sorry; 

it could look like depending on your exact structure

`
    xquery version "3.0";

    declare default element namespace "http://schemas.openehr.org/v1";

    for $n in fn:collection('/db/apps/compositions')//data[position() = 1]

    return fn:data($n/name/value)
`

Comment: Here you can find a full example: https://github.com/ppazos/clinical-database-tests/blob/master/compositions/composition_8741_0.xml As you will see, **version/data** element has descendant elements (children, grandchildren, ...) that are also named _data_ and have **name/value**. The query is returning all the **data/name/value** declared in the document, not just the **version/data/name/value** that I'm trying to get.